# How do I set up a PPPoE connection?

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, internet, pppoe

I have a new broadband connection and i want to connect it using ubuntu. I have a **user name** and a **password**, nothing more.

I want to know how to connect to such network, how to create the connection?

Comment: Do you have a cable modem?  Do you also have a router (Ethernet and/or WiFi)?

Comment: No not a cable modem, but a nanostation(as they said)? And host system is directly connected to the device. With a adapter in between and powering the device and forwarding the data packets to the system.

Comment: Brand. model, service provider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options for PPPoE as I understand from your question.

## Option 1

DSL provided by *Network Manager*. Just go to *Edit Connections…* in the *Network Settings* and you will see DSL on the last tab and *Add* the connection.

[image: Network Connections overview]
[image: DSL connection configuration]

## Option 2

In your terminal type `sudo pppoeconf` and follow the instruction and setup the connection. You can control the connection with `sudo pon` and `sudo poff`.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same, it works.... I did the first step

Comment: The command is called `pppoeconf` with 3 p not 2. Unfortunately I cannot suggest an edit because I have to write 6 characters at least.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by setting up a DSL Connection.

1. Make sure your wired network, is set to automatic DHCP.
2. Create a DSL Connection.. and provide your username & password. (For me, I didn't had to change any of my PPPOE Settings)
3. Save the Connection
4. Connect using the DSL connection you just created

Comment: Sorry how do I connect? I dont understand step 4. There is no way I could connect, no right click, nothing. How does that work? thanks

Comment: @Kave, Your connection should appear on the list after you save the connection.

Comment: thanks, yeah its tricky a bit to find the list. now I know :)

Comment: that's didn't work for me (ubuntu 12.04 32bit)

Answer (score 3):

If someone looking for the PPPOe setup for Ubuntu 20.04LTS , h may not find that option in `Setting>Network` as i have given a picture of my Ubuntu 20.04!

There is no option for DSL/PPPOe and i don't know why!

[image]

You can create using these commands :

`nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "interface_name"`

`set pppoe.username isp_provided_username`

`set pppoe.password isp_provided_password`

`save`

Answer (score 0):

Setup a manual Ethernet connection ..

Try the instructions for Mac OS-X (page 4.) for the IP address settings.

http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/Nano_Quick_Set-up.pdf

best guess on these settings for Ubuntu: (and you should enable 'Connect automatically')

[image]

Comment: I dont have any of those information. No gateway information, no dns servers, no host address. Just a username and password.