# Cant find where to enter internet password and user name for DSL Ethernet

Tags: networking, pppoe, adsl

In order to connect to the internet in Windows 7, there is a dialog box in which one enters the username and password in order to connect. I have diligently looked in many places, but I can not find where this internet username and password dialog box is in Ubuntu.

I am definitely connected to Ethernet. Ubuntu is clearly showing my IP address, Ethernet address, etc.

It is my understanding that the connection where I am is a DSL connection. The DSL company needs a password and username in order to access the account. Where could I enter that?

Comment: pppoe? You might look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/83869/setting-up-a-pppoe-connection-in-ubuntu

Comment: Are you not able to connect to the ADSL model/router *setup*, using your browser? There should instruction on how to log on in the manual (for ADSL modem). It is usually as simple as opening browser and typing an address of: **192.168.0.1** (this may vary for your particular device)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the details in the router is preferrable; however, if it must be set in the computer, right-click the Network Manager icon, select 'Edit Connections' and select the DSL tab. Fill in your details there.

Comment: OK, I am on the net for now. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.