# Conn to internet via LAN PPPoE

Tags: 12.10, networking, internet, lan, pppoe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up a pppoe connection in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83869/setting-up-a-pppoe-connection-in-ubuntu)

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 today along with Windows. On Windows I am connected to LAN *(My internet comes through a ethernet cable)*. I have a PPPoE connection with a username and password through which I connect to the internet. I want to do the same on Ubuntu.

How to make the connection in Ubuntu ?( I know how do it on Windows)