# How to connect to internet using wired PPPOE connection?

Tags: internet, wired

I tried following the [Internet how-to guide](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetHowto) to connect to my ISP, but I got stuck after the instruction to run `sudo pppoeconf`. It asks for my ISP account password, when I try to enter it, no text appears on the screen, and when I press enter, it says that the password is incorrect. But, I am sure that the password is the same one I am using in Windows 7.

Please let me know how to proceed further?

Comment: Assuming your unit itself is CPE but not a router. Hope this helps you > http://askubuntu.com/a/89713/179042

Comment: It may be possible that you are asked prior to entering your ISP internet password for a so-called 'keyring encrypted password' by the 'keyring service' which encrypts networking data for security reasons. Do you recall to have been created such a password in the past while trying to make another Internet connection? If so then read this article to delete that keyring password: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1653-how-to-use-keyrings-in-ubuntu/       It is also possible that you just don't type the internet password for your ISP account correctly, capital letters included.

Answer (score 8):

Just follow these steps:

1. Check that the ethernet cable is properly connected
2. Open Terminal
3. Run `sudo pppoeconf`
4. Enter root password
5. Answer all the question that will be asked with an answer "Yes"
6. Finally type `pon dsl-provider`

To stop connection run `poff dsl-provider`

Answer (score 2):

You need to be `root` to setup a `pppoe` connection with `pppoeconf`. Try this code in a terminal window:

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

You're saying that you can't see the field for typing the password, and maybe you should exit to console terminal (press<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and login as `user` which is your username for Ubuntu, and then try to run command `sudo pppoeconf` to see what happens.

After setup for `pppoe` configuration begins, you are told what to do next step by step. You should use the default settings suggested in `pppoeconf` for MTU, DNS servers and so on (press YES each time you are asked for it). You can change these settings later on if you have to, there are plenty of tutorials for that. Also, when asked if you want internet connection to be triggered at start-up press YES, it makes things easier for you.

`Pppoeconf` asks you for both your `username` and the `password` assigned to you by you Internet service provider, the same that you use in Windows 7 when you setup your Internet connection. First type in your `username`, press OK, and at next screen you should be able to type your 'password' and press OK again.

`Pppoeconf` tool for Internet configuration and Gnome network Manager are somehow conflicting one with each other so you have to remove 'gnome network manager' before using `pppoeconf` or you can forget about `pppoeconf` and setup a new DSL connection using `gnome network manager` which allows you to make a new `PPPOE` connection in the DSL section (press ADD button to make a new ppp connection, and then use your `username` and password, same as in WIN7).

Default commands for starting and stoping a connection configured with `pppoeconf` are:

`sudo pon dsl-provider` (this one starts or restarts your DSL connection)

`sudo poff dsl-provider` (this one stops your DSL connection)

You should remember these commands because it could happen after reboot to see that Internet is not working even if your DSL connection is up and running. To solve this problem you must stop connection in a terminal, and then restart it, and that is why you need to remember how to start and stop a DSl connection configured with `pppoeconf`.

Good luck with this one, I know it is a little bit confusing for the moment but you made the right choice. You get more speed for your Internet connection and better results with `pppoeconf` than with Gnome Network Manager and its DSL connection.

Answer (score -1):

You have to ask your ISP about the configuration parameters of the router. Most of the time, the routers are configured by opening a browser (i.e. Firefox) and entering 192.168.1.1 (or any address asigned to the router). Once in, you have to type the admin username and password, then you'll be able to configure the router properly using its interface (GUI). But, remember, first of all, call/contact your ISP and ask for the configuration parameters.
Admin username and password is the same no matter if you're on Windows or Ubuntu, because you are configuring the router not your system.

Comment: Who said he has a router?  Since he apparently had to configure pppoe and connect each time under Windows, it's a pretty good bet he doesn't.