# Connecting cable/fibre internet using PPPoE in Ubuntu

Tags: internet, pppoe

I have Cable/fibre named VIVA BROADBAND (not sure, as the provider says it is Fibre, but provider is actually a television cable provider) internet which uses PPPoE/Russia PPPoE username password authentication and provides dynamic addresses.

ISP gave me an username and password. Note that it is *not DSL/ADSL*. I used to use router (non ADSL router), that just connects me to WAN using PPPoE username and password, and IP addresses are assigned dynamically.

In Windows, I can do this easily by creating a new connection using broadband option PPPoE, key in username and password, and get connected.

How can I connect this cable PPPoE in Ubuntu? All other questions in SU and AskUbuntu tells about only DSL connections.

Update: This is how I connect using my router: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT4GB.jpg,

[image]

How can I achieve the same without the router (directly connecting the LAN Ethernet cable to my Ubuntu machine)?

Comment: It just doesn't connect. But, the connection is working fine through a non DSL router. (Tplink TL-WR740N).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to internet using wired PPPOE connection?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406300/how-to-connect-to-internet-using-wired-pppoe-connection)

Comment: That's for DSL only. Non DSL cable connections are not working. There are no options available for non DSL connections in pppoeconf or network manager.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/833564/unable-to-connect-to-the-internet-via-ethernet-using-a-pppoe-though-it-works/833891?noredirect=1#comment1272914_833891 as well

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set up your non-DSL PPPoE using `networkmanager`in your gui or you can use `pppoeconf`

further details can be found with the command `man ppoeconf`

Comment: pppoeconf asks for DSL connection info. Tried, but not connecting though. Mine is cable internet. Need procedure for `networkmanager` usage.

Comment: I want to achieve this: http://imgur.com/a/pIIir without the router.

Answer (score 0):

The media shouldn't make a difference whether cable or fibre. For Dual Access PPPOE (AKA Russia PPOE) your first connection is to the providers resources and then a PPTP connection is setup to the Internet as discussed [here] [0]  Since you have a router that does this in firmware, I would continue to use that as it allows for more flexibility in your LAN and is the simplest solution.

Dual access means a two-staged connection with the Internet service provider (uplink):

connection to the provider through Ethernet-interface to assign an IP-address,routes, etc. with DHCP or with static settings.

•connection with the use of the protocol group like “point-to-point”, (PPPoE, PPTP,L2TP) on the second stage
Connection to the provider network is carried out through Ethernet-port ; an IP-address,routes, name servers are assigned to the client by the provider.

Upon completion of the first stage of connection a client gets access to the internal resources of the provider, but not to the Internet.

On the second stage the connection through PPTP or L2TP protocols is established with the assignment of a new default route, new name servers and a new IP-address on the new interface ( named pppX). Upon completion of the second stage a client obtains access to the Internet.

this should give you some idea of what your router is doing for you behind the scenes. Your ISP should be able to provide you with all the information required to connect. In effect you need a PPTP connection setup over your initial connection to your ISP. If your initial connection isn't stable enough for you to have time to setup the PPTP connection over it, I would discuss the problem with the ISP.

As an aside, many cable internet providers use a registered MAC address to determine network access. (This is how it works in my neck of the woods) You can likely locate the routers MAC address on the Status page under WAN as shown in Figure 4-1 Router Status on or about page 17 of [your router manual.](http://setuprouter.com/router/tp-link/tl-wr740n/manual-737.pdf) Then you can change your Ethernet cards Mac address as decribed [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81648/how-do-i-change-spoof-my-mac-address-and-easily-switch-between-multiple-ones)

Comment: I could enter only the username. Password field is non editable for me (not greyed out, but not clickable).

Comment: Yes. I've been around several internet connectivity procedures, and used most of the connectivity types. This one is so odd.

Comment: My bad, the password is actually available by selecting the option in the right. Entered the password. Still, `Save` is greyed out. It requires a gateway. And, I'm sure, this is a cable/FTTH broadband. No such VPN needed actually. Here's what I get http://imgur.com/a/BP0bD

Comment: @unix_root see updated Answer

Comment: Ouch. You misunderstood. I can connect to Internet through router (that's the image I've shared in the question). I want to connect this `without a router`. I just have a LAN ethernet cable. I can do this in Windows machine (explained in question). Wanna do the same in Ubuntu.

Comment: I get internet though: LAN Ethernet cable ---> Wireless Router ---> Wirelessly connected to Ubuntu machine. What I need is: LAN Ethernet cable ---> Ubuntu machine.

Comment: But, if not, how did you suggest me to enter my router gateway address in the gateway field? Or, am I missing something here? O.O

Comment: As per my router, it doesn't make a secondary connection (Dual Access/Russia PPPoE). See my first [image attachment]( http://imgur.com/a/pIIir) in the question. It's normal PPPoE connection, not dual access.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/pIIir states clearly at the top  PPPoE/Russia PPPoE  hence the confusion. Hopefully someone else can assist you with eliminating your router from your environment. Best of luck.

Comment: That's the common option. "Secondary connection" in the image states clearly that Dual Access Russia PPPoE is disabled.